# Upload a file on amazon S3 with PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, upload, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file on my amazon S3 bucket via the PHP SDK. However my script doesn't work, I have a blank page without any error or exception message.

EDIT : After enabled "display_error" in php.ini. I have the error message below (looks like the sdk is not working on my side).

Thanks to @datasage  . The problem was that aws.phar needs cURL to be installed on the machine to work.

> **sudo apt-get install php5-curl**

```
<?php

require 'aws.phar';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

$bucket = 'infactr';
$keyname = 'sample';
// $filepath should be absolute path to a file on disk                      
$filepath = 'image.jpg';

// Instantiate the client.
$s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
    'key'    => 'Key',
    'secret' => 'privatekey',
    'region' => 'eu-west-1'

    ));

try {
    // Upload data.
    $result = $s3->putObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key'    => $keyname,
        'SourceFile'   => $filepath,
        'ACL'    => 'public-read',
        'ContentType' => 'image/jpeg'
    ));

    // Print the URL to the object.
    echo $result['ObjectURL'] . "\n";
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}

?>
```

Here is the error message that I get.

> Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST - assumed 'CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST' in phar:///var/www/s3/aws.phar/Aws/S3/S3Client.php on line 242 Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT - assumed 'CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT' in phar:///var/www/s3/aws.phar/Aws/S3/S3Client.php on line 242 Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLE_PARTIAL_FILE - assumed 'CURLE_PARTIAL_FILE' in phar:///var/www/s3/aws.phar/Aws/S3/S3Client.php on line 242 Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLE_WRITE_ERROR - assumed 'CURLE_WRITE_ERROR' in phar:///var/www/s3/aws.phar/Aws/S3/S3Client.php on line 242 Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLE_READ_ERROR - assumed 'CURLE_READ_ERROR' in phar:///var/www/s3/aws.phar/Aws/S3/S3Client.php on line 242 Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEOUTED - assumed 'CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEOUTED' in phar:///var/www/s3/aws.phar/Aws/S3/S3Client.php on line 242 Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLE_SSL_CONNECT_ERROR - assumed 'CURLE_SSL_CONNECT_ERROR' in phar:///var/www/s3/aws.phar/Aws/S3/S3Client.php on line 242 Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLE_HTTP_PORT_FAILED - assumed 'CURLE_HTTP_PORT_FAILED' in phar:///var/www/s3/aws.phar/Aws/S3/S3Client.php on line 242 Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLE_GOT_NOTHING - assumed 'CURLE_GOT_NOTHING' in phar:///var/www/s3/aws.phar/Aws/S3/S3Client.php on line 242 Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLE_SEND_ERROR - assumed 'CURLE_SEND_ERROR' in phar:///var/www/s3/aws.phar/Aws/S3/S3Client.php on line 242 Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLE_RECV_ERROR - assumed 'CURLE_RECV_ERROR' in phar:///var/www/s3/aws.phar/Aws/S3/S3Client.php on line 242 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\Common\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'The PHP cURL extension must be installed to use Guzzle.' in phar:///var/www/s3/aws.phar/Guzzle/Http/Client.php:70 Stack trace: #0 phar:///var/www/s3/aws.phar/Aws/Common/Client/AbstractClient.php(78): Guzzle\Http\Client->_*construct('//s3-eu-w...', Object(Guzzle\Common\Collection)) #1 phar:///var/www/s3/aws.phar/Aws/Common/Client/ClientBuilder.php(252): Aws\Common\Client\AbstractClient->*_construct(Object(Aws\Common\Credentials\Credentials), Object(Aws\S3\S3Signature), Object(Guzzle\Common\Collection)) #2 phar:///var/www/s3/aws.phar/Aws/S3/S3Client.php(206): Aws\Common\Client\ClientBuilder->build() #3 /var/www/s3/index2.php(19): Aws\S3\S3Client::factory(Array) #4 {main} thrown in phar:///var/www/s3/aws.phar/Guzzle/Http/Client.php on line 70

Comment: Enable display_errors in php.ini. You may have a different kind of error.

Comment: That is just a comment, the value is in a different place in the file. Any lines starting with ; are comments.

Comment: I've done it. You can see the error message in my initial post.

Comment: It appears that you are missing curl. If you are linux you can usually install it via the package manager package would be named something similar to `php-curl`.

Comment: Thanks, I've just installed cURL but I still have issues with my script. I edit my first post. Thanks again for you support

Comment: PHP var names are case sensative. Check `$filePath` and `$filepath`

Comment: Yes. I found it. Thanks again. You made my day. Not kidding.